# extract every nth character from a string

Tags: shell, shell-script, string

I am trying to figure out a solution for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161885/using-awk-to-identify-the-number-identical-columns) question. My approach to this problem  so far is as below.

- Append all the characters together to make it a long string.
- After the above step, remove all the white spaces or tab spaces so that we will just have one big string.

I was able to establish the above steps with the below command.

```
column -s '\t' inputfile | tr -d '[:space:]'
```

So for an input file like this,

```
1   0   0   0   0   0

0   1   1   1   0   0
```

After applying the above command I have the values as,

```
100000011100
```

Now in this big string I am trying to apply an approach as below.

Extract every 6<sup>th</sup> character (as the original OP wants), and append it to an array element till the end of the string.

So basically, with the above step, I am trying to create the array elements as,

`10` (1<sup>st</sup> and 7<sup>th</sup> character), `01` (2<sup>nd</sup> and 8<sup>th</sup> character), `01` (3<sup>rd</sup> and 9<sup>th</sup> character), `01` (4<sup>th</sup> and 10<sup>th</sup> character), `00` (5<sup>th</sup> and 11<sup>th</sup> character), `00` (6<sup>th</sup> and 12<sup>th</sup> character)
.

So my question is, how could I extract every n<sup>th</sup> character so that I could add them to an array to proceed further? (n=6, in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Two lines

Here is a pure-`bash` solution that produces a `bash` array:

```
s="100000011100"
array=($(
    for ((i=0; i<${#s}-6; i++))
    do
        echo "${s:$i:1}${s:$((i+6)):1}"
    done
    ))
echo "${array[@]}"
```

This produces the same output as shown in the question:

```
10 01 01 01 00 00
```

The key element here is the use of bash's *substring expansion*.  Bash allows the extraction substrings from a variable, say `parameter`, via `${parameter:offset:length}`.  In our case, the offset is determined by the loop variable `i` and the length is always `1`.

#### General Solution For Any Number of Lines

Suppose, for example, that our original string has 18 characters and we want to extract the i-th, the i+6-th, and the i+12-th characters for i from 0 to 5.  Then:

```
s="100000011100234567"
array=($(
    for ((i=0; i<6; i++))
    do
        new=${s:$i:1}
        for ((j=i+6; j<${#s}; j=j+6))
        do 
            new="$new${s:$j:1}"
        done
        echo "$new"
    done
    ))

echo "${array[@]}"
```

This produces the output:

```
102 013 014 015 006 007
```

This same code extends to an arbitrary number of 6-character lines.  For example, if `s` has three lines (18 characters):

```
s="100000011100234567abcdef"
```

Then, the output becomes:

```
102a 013b 014c 015d 006e 007f
```

Comment: thanks. I have the same problem as I have mentioned in Gnouc's answer. If I have 3 lines, it seems to break.

Comment: @Ramesh See update.

Comment: cool. This one also works as expected. Thanks again for providing a bash solution.

Comment: I have used your solution to address the original problem of the OP in the question I linked. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ramesh So, this is combined with `wc -w`.  Nice.  +1 for your answer to the other question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `perl`:

```
$ echo 100000011100 | perl -nle '
    for ($i = 0; $i < length()/2; $i++) {
        print substr($_,$i,1), substr($_,$i+6,1);
    }
'
10
01
01
01
00
00
```

It works for two lines. If you want to work with arbitrary of lines, you should process lines directly, instead of building big string. With this input:

```
1   0   0   0   0   0                                                           
0   1   1   1   0   0                                                           
0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Try:

```
$ perl -anle '
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $#F; $i++) {
      push @{$h{$i}}, $F[$i];
    }
    END {
        print @{$h{$_}} for keys %h;
    }
' file
000
010
000
100
010
010
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I have 3 lines, I want to get the substrings as `101`, `001` and so on. But I am getting only 2 characters with this approach.

Comment: @Ramesh: See my updated.

Comment: cool. This one works. You should probably add this one as the answer to the other question.

Answer (score 3):

As a shell solution, `getopts` is probably easiest. The thing about `getopts` is that it is POSIX-specified to do exactly what you're asking - process a byte-stream in a shell-loop. I know that sounds weird, because, if you're like me before I learned this, you're probably thinking, *well, gee, I thought it was supposed to handle command-line switches.* Which is true, but so is the first thing. Consider:

```
-thisisonelongstringconsistingofseparatecommandlineswitches
```

Yes, `getopts` has to handle that. It has to split that char by char in a loop and return to you each character in either the shell variable `$OPTARG` or in another that you specify by name all depending on how specific you get when you call it. What's more, it has to return errors in shell variables and *save its progress* when it does in the shell variable `$OPTIND` so it can *resume right where it left off* if you can somehow address it. And it has to do the whole job without invoking a single subshell.

So let's say we have:

```
arg=$(seq -s '' 1000); set --
while getopts :0123456789 v -"${arg}"
do [ "$((i=$i+1<6?$i+1:0))" -gt 0 ] ||
set "$@" "$v"
done
```

Hmmm.... I wonder if it worked?

```
echo "$((${#arg}/6))" "$#"
482 482
```

That's nice...

```
eval '
printf %.1s\\n "${arg#'"$(printf %0$((124*6-1))d | tr 0 \?)"'}" "${124}"'
4
4
```

So, as you can see, the `getopts` command completely set the array for every sixth byte in the string. And it doesn't have to be numbers like this - nor must it even be shell safe characters - and you needn't even specify the target chars as I did above with `01234565789` either. I've tested this repeatedly in a lot of shells and they all just work. There are some quirks - `bash` will throw away the first character if it is a whitespace character - `dash` accepts the `:` colon as a specified parameter even though it is just about the only POSIX specifically forbids. But none of that matters because `getopts` still deposits the current opt char's value in `$OPTARG` even when it returns you an error *(represented by a ? assigned to your specified opt var)* and otherwise explictly unsets `$OPTARG` unless you've declared an option should have an argument. And the whitespace thing is kind of a good thing - it only discards a *leading* space, which is excellent, because, when working with unknown values, you can do:

```
getopts : o -" $unknown_value"
```

...to kick off the loop without any danger of the first character actually being in your accepted args string - which would result in `getopts` sticking the whole thing in `$OPTARG` at once - as an argument.

Here's another example:

```
OPTIND=1
while getopts : o -" $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=16 count=1 2>/dev/null)"                         
do printf '\\%04o' "'$OPTARG"; done  

\0040\0150\0071\0365\0320\0070\0161\0064\0274\0115\0012\0215\0222\0271\0146\0057\0166
```

I set `$OPTIND=1` in the first line because I just used `getopts` and, until you reset it, it expects its next call to continue where it left off - it wants `"${arg2}"` in other words. But I don't feel like giving and I'm doing a different thing now, so I let it know by resetting `$OPTIND` at which point it's good to go.

In this one I used `zsh` - which doesn't quibble about a leading space - and so the first character is octal 40 - the space character. I don't usually use `getopts` in that way, though - I usually use it to *avoid* doing a `write()` for each byte and instead assign its output - which comes in a variable - to another shell variable - as I did above with `set` after a fashion. Then, when I'm ready I can take the whole string and when I do usually strip the first byte.

Comment: you gotta give a little to get the little. for shame, me.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is the first thing that pops into my mind.

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | sed 's/.\{5\}\(.\)/\1/g'
6bhntz
```

Match 5 characters, capture the 6th, and replace them all with that captured character.

This will however have an issue if the length of the string isn't an exact multiple of 6:

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | sed 's/.\{5\}\(.\)/\1/g' 
6bhntuvwxy
```

But we can fix this by altering the `sed` a little:

```
$ echo 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy | sed 's/.\{1,5\}\(.\{0,1\}\)/\1/g'
6bhnt
```

Due to the greedy nature of regex, the variable length matches will match as much as they can, and if there's nothing left for the capture, then it doesn't capture, and the characters are just deleted.

Comment: Thanks. So I will still need a loop to store the sed's output to an array variable?

Comment: Not necessarily. `read -a foo < <(echo 1234567890ab | sed 's/.\{1,5\}\(.\{0,1\}\)/\1 /g')`

Comment: your solution seems to work even if I have more than 2 lines. But I still get the last line as the array value. Instead I want all the values to be stored in my array. This is the command am trying. 

`read -a array_elements < <(column -s '\t' inputfile | tr -d '[:space:]' | sed 's/.\{5\}\(.\)/\1/g')`

Comment: Read the rest of the answer. It explains the issue.